# Excel Match conditional formatting

Tags: excel

Hi I am using the formula =MATCH(A1,B:B,0)>0 with conditional formatting to highlight a match in a cell but from a different sheet.  Any suggestions as to how I highlight the full row and not just one cell please?

Comment: Are you trying to highlight the whole row if a certain cell matches a cell in another sheet? Or highlight each cell in the row if that cell matches another cell in another sheet.  Some sample data and expected results would help

Comment: Sheet 1 3 Columns Name, Hospital Number, Diagnosis
Sheet 2 3 Columns < Name, Hospital Number, Diagnosis

If Hospital number in second sheet matches Sheet 1, highlight full row with matching hospital number in Sheet 1

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your conditional formatting rule look at the "applies to" entry. in the table. See the area highlighted in yellow below. Make sure that includes the entire range of cells you want to highlight, not just one column. If your rows span columns A-F, you may want something like $A$2:$F$500.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks I have tried this but still doesn't work for me.  Does it work for you?

Comment: For your rule, try changing B:B to $B:$B. I get odd formatting when I don't lock the columns use for the rule.

Comment: Thanks all sorted now.